# What is the clean way to call all the previous functions after each move? How to not repeat this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie and I need help, please. I have been looking for a solution for long time, but cannot go further. I have a chess table with pieces without repeating codes, but I am stuck at a part when the pieces should move to positions I define. Its a chess analysis and all position is defined by me. This code below works, but it is repetitive.

1. I want the code not repetitive
2. if I click any button (except the first move), then all the previous button click should fire as well at once. So one move follow another.
3. if the above things would work, I also want to remove those chess pieces that was defined after a certain button. So if I am at the position of #move4 and I click the button #move3, then I want to move the chess piece back to position #move3

Thank you very much for help and for any advice.

HTML code:

```
  <button id="move1" class="move">d4</button>
  <button id="move2" class="move">Nf6</button>
  <button id="move3" class="move">c4</button>
  <button id="move4" class="move">g6</button>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#move1').on('click', function () {

    pieces[19].y = 4;

    drawBoard();
    drawAllPieces();
});
$('#move2').on('click', function () {

    pieces[11].y = 2;
    pieces[11].x = 5;

    $("#move1").click();
    drawBoard();
    drawAllPieces();
});

$('#move3').on('click', function () {

    pieces[18].y = 4;

    $("#move1").click();
    $("#move2").click();
    drawBoard();
    drawAllPieces();
});

$('#move4').on('click', function () {

    pieces[6].y = 2;

    $("#move1").click();
    $("#move2").click();
    $("#move3").click();
    drawBoard();
    drawAllPieces();
});
```

Comment: What is `pieces` array?

Comment: pieces array stores 32 chess pieces (images) and the starting positions of each piece is defined  with x,y `var pieces = new Array(32); ` For example, one of the black rook is stored in pieces[8] and its starting position is `piece.x = 0; piece.y = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to make it dynamic -

```
for(const i of [1,2,3,4]) {
  $(`#move${i}`').on('click', function () {

    pieces[19].y = 4;

    drawBoard();
    drawAllPieces();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Based on this code, moving to the new position (pieces[19].y) is going to be executed on any button click in the array, but the idea is that if I click button1, then one certain move is executed and if I click button2, then the next position and the previous positions should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the moves in an array then you only need a single handler for the click.

```
<button data-move="0">d4</button>
<button data-move="1">Nf6</button>
<button data-move="2">c4</button>
<button data-move="3">g6</button>

var moves = [
    { piece: 19, y: 4 },
    { piece: 11, y: 2, x: 5 },
    { piece: 18, y: 4 },
    { piece: 6, y: 2 },
];

$('button').on('click', function () {
    var index = +$(this).attr('data-move');

    for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        var data = moves[i];

        if (!isNaN(data.y)) // check if the data has y property
            pieces[data.piece] = data.y;

        if (!isNaN(data.x)) // check if the data has x property
            pieces[data.piece] = data.x;
    }

    drawBoard();
    drawAllPieces();

});
```

Comment: looks like a solution, but half of the chess pieces just disappear when I click button1. Thank you for this, I will try to work it out.

Comment: I just realized it would only make the move at the given index. I added `for loop` to make all the moves up to the given index. So when you click at `<button data-move="3">` it will process all 4 moves defined in the `moves` array

Comment: Now I got an error that I haven't seen before. The pieces were moving with my repetitive code, so I have no idea why this error came up when implementing your code: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'"

`var chessCanvas = document.getElementById("board");
var chessContext = chessCanvas.getContext("2d");
`

Comment: `function drawPiece(p) {
    if (!p.killed)
        chessContext.drawImage(p.image,
            (50 - p.width) / 2 + (50 * p.x),
            50 - p.height + (50 * p.y),
            p.width,
            p.height);
}`

if I click a button, pieces are disappearing

Comment: Are you sure the image in the `p.image` is loaded before you call `drawImage`?

Comment: yes,its loaded. Still not working. Thanks anyway, I keep trying!